# Node.js file upload from command line interface

Tags: node.js, file-upload, command-line-interface

I am creating custom command line interface(CLI) for our application. Now, I need to upload a file from CLI. Can we upload a file from CLI? Let say I'm in project folder location `abc` in terminal and it contains a `.js` file. I want to get that file and upload into server.

I used [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) with [express](https://github.com/strongloop/express) framework for uploading files from browser with html form. But I don't know how to do this from command line interface. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to upload file - using HTTP, SSH or FTP ?

Comment: I have a REST api server end point with POST method for uploading file. So HTTP method is needed.

Comment: use `request` library: https://github.com/request/request#streaming

Comment: I forgot to mention. I am using `request` only for login operation and for some other `get` operations. So can we do file upload too? I will check it out. thanks.

Comment: Hi I checked the link. But still struggling. I want to send `headers` with HTTP POST request such as session token and app key.

Comment: It is possible to send custom headers with post request options. Something like:  `fs.createReadStream('file.json').pipe(request.post(options))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing an answer to my own question as nobody has posted an answer. Followed @hassansin guide from comment section and [this](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads), that solved my problem. Thanks stackoverflow.

```
var formData = {
    file: fs.createReadStream('local/file/path/test.js'),
};

request.post(
    { url:'http://server/file/upload/url', 
      headers:{ 'X-SessionToken-Key':'XXXXXXXXX',
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'},
      formData: formData
    }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
          }
        console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    });
```

Comment: Nice! I used this with jest tests, super easy.